# How to resolve recursive dependencies of a Grunt plugin from the parent project?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

*(There seem to be several similar questions, but none of them apply or have valid answers).*

I am writing a Grunt plugin that depends on `grunt-shell` and `grunt-concurrent` plugins.

```
/* tasks/myTask.js */
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');
```

Running tasks from within my plugin's working directory works as expected. However, when I try to use my plugin's tasks in another project, I get:

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-concurrent" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-shell" not found. Is it installed?
```

Is there any way for my grunt plugin to utilize other plugins without requiring them in every project that uses my plugin?

My research so far with not much success:

- Grunt documentation is pretty sparse: http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins
- `#grunt` on IRC is a ghost town
- https://github.com/ruyadorno/extend-grunt-plugin
- https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/696 (issue ended up closed without resolution)

Comment: How is your plugin structured? Doesn't it have its own `package.json` with dependencies?

Comment: It's structured like a standard NPM module, and init'ed with `grunt init`. (EDIT: initially posted the `devDependencies` and `dependencies` keys here, but formatting got all messed up). It's quite standard though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I misread your question originally. Yes, it does have its dependencies listed and installed correctly (as `dependencies`, NOT `devDependencies`), but the project that uses the plugin isn't finding those dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(answering my own question - please correct if I'm still wrong)*

> Is there any way for my grunt plugin to utilize other plugins without requiring them in every project that uses my plugin?

No, there isn't.

For now, you may be able to use peerDependencies, but they are deprecated in NPM 3+, so this is not a solution.

You will need to provide documentation with your plugin to indicate which other plugins need to be installed alongside it for proper functionality.